# Increasing the size of the first-letter no longer centres text correctly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-size

If I may direct you to the following JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/93kepaL6/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.MT {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  row-gap: 0px;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

.MLC {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 0px;
  column-gap: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.L1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

.L2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

.L3 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}


/*
    .L3::first-letter {
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 15rem;
    }
    */
```

```html
<div class="MT">
  <div class="MLC">
    <div class="L1">AAA</div>
    <div class="L2">BBB</div>
    <div class="L3">CCC</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that the text is centered as expected. However uncommenting the `.L3::first-letter` selector at the bottom of the css will result in the text then being off-centre. Furthermore, increasing the font-size within this selector further places the text to the left hand side.

Why is this?

Comment: Here's a trick: add `outline: 1px solid white` to `.MLC` to see where exactly it is. In this particular case, it remains centered as a child of `.MT`. This is not the case with its children's text nodes, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grid layout centered the `.MLC` element itself, but not the text content.

Text is always left-aligned within its container by default (for LTR languages, at least). It only appeared to be horizontally centered before because the three `<div>`s were all close to the same width.

You can add the following rule to `.MLC` to center it:

```
.MLC {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Debugging tip:**

If you run into a situation like this in the future, try adding an outline to the affected elements to help visualize what is going on. For example:

```
div {
  outline: solid 1px red;
}
```